# Does s3fs.S3FileSystem() always need a specific region setting?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, permission-denied, python-s3fs

What I'm trying to do is to connect a s3 bucket from my EC2 machine.

This error comes up if I don't set the `endpoint_url` in `s3fs.S3FileSystem()`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 246, in _call_s3
    out = await method(**additional_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 155, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 1064, in _info
    out = await self._simple_info(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 984, in _simple_info
    **self.req_kw,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 265, in _call_s3
    raise translate_boto_error(err)
PermissionError: Access Denied
```

However, I was able to fix it adding the `endpoint_url` in `s3fs.S3FileSystem()` to specify the region.

```
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key=MYKEY,
                       secret=SECRET,
                       client_kwargs={
                           'endpoint_url':'https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com'
                           })
```

**I'm wondering if s3fs requires the specific region because there is no strict guidance in the documentation..!**

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by passing `client_kwargs` to the constructor:

```py
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(client_kwargs={'region_name': 'us-east-1'})
```

References:

- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html
- https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#s3fs.core.S3FileSystem

Answer (score 0):

it seems that s3fs surely requires the specific region. if you've specified profile in your aws credentials and specified region in your aws config, you can use profile like this:

```py
from aiobotocore.session import AioSession
s3=s3fs.S3FileSystem(session=AioSession(profile='your_profile_name'))
```

It works for me.
Tips: 'your_profile_name' means profile in aws credentials, like this:

```
[your_profile_name]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxx
```